# How to prevent delete on table in mysql without any notification?

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

As per my project requirement, I need to implement database audit log to record any delete/update activity from backend on certain tables in MySQL database. As per my knowledge, the obvious way for this is using triggers.

After some searches I found we can throw an exception in triggers but as per my requirement I do not need to show any error message for this kind of activity, instead, I just need to prevent Update/Delete and log the activity in the audit table.

What will be the best way for this?

Comment: Is mysql the only technology here or do you have some sort of user interface?

Comment: Yes, we are using MySQL as database. And I need to do this from database end.